# Индекс находится вне границ массива

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Иногда после ввода чисел в массив, программа выводит ошибку компиляции "Индекс находится вне границ массива", хотя кол-во чисел может быть любым, знающие люди, помогите...

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string noelem = "Элементов не найдено";
           int sum = 0;
           int pr = 1;
           int[] mas = new int[TB1.Lines.Length];
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < mas.Length; i++)
               mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(TB1.Lines[i]);
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < mas.Length; i++)
               if (mas[i] < 50)
                   pr *= mas[i];
               else 
               if (mas[i] > 100)
                   sum += mas[i];
           //
           for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
               if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
               else
                   mas[i] = pr;
           }
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
               mas[i] = sum;
           }
               //
               TB2.Clear();
           for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
           if (pr == 1) TB2.Text = noelem.ToString();
           else
               TB2.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
           for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++)
               if (sum == 0) TB3.Text = noelem.ToString();
           else
           TB3.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
       }
```

Comment: Почему это во многих циклах верхний предел задан конкретной константой? Кроме того "при вводе чисел"  - это ошибка не компиляции, а рантайма (времени выполнения)

Comment: @MBo, какие константы, ты про i что-ли?

Comment: @MBo, Просто нужно вывести только сумму и только произведение

Comment: Вот это что?  for (int i = 1; i < **2**

Comment: @MBo для вывода нужно вывести только одно число, поэтому я и изменил предел для i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нескольких циклах for используются константы для задания верхнего предела, при это игнорируется реальное количество элементов.

Таким образом, при малом количестве элементов в `TB1.Lines` будет произведено обращение к несуществующему элементу массива. Например, при наличии всего двух элементов следующий цикл попытается обратиться к третьему

```
 for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
               mas[i] = sum;
           }
```

Comment: т.е. стоит везде писать i <mas.Length? Тогда как вывести только сумму и произведение?

Comment: Зачем вообще сумму и произведение вносить в массив? Вот сами переменные sum и pr и вывести.

Comment: похоже вопрос исчерпан, теперь похоже новый нужен, по выводу переменных...